# nginx: segfault at 30 ip 0000558398c6b2d9 sp 00007ffee2bda1e0 error 4 in nginx[558398a8e000+4c2000]

Tags: nginx

I am running Latest Nginx with PHP-FPM on Ubuntu 16.04. The VPS is continuously getting "segfault at 30 ip" error. The error was also with Nginx v1.13.10 too.

I am unable to diagnose it myself. Searched a lot but couldn't find the solution.

**kern.log**

```
Apr  6 08:38:55 EE-Test-Server kernel: [39400.262830] nginx[24682]: segfault at 30 ip 0000558398c6b2d9 sp 00007ffee2bda2b0 error 4 in nginx[558398a8e000+4c2000]
Apr  6 10:17:20 EE-Test-Server kernel: [45305.179307] nginx[24811]: segfault at 30 ip 0000558398c6b2d9 sp 00007ffee2bda1e0 error 4 in nginx[558398a8e000+4c2000]
Apr  6 11:13:59 EE-Test-Server kernel: [48704.515495] nginx[25701]: segfault at 30 ip 0000558398c6b2d9 sp 00007ffee2bda240 error 4 in nginx[558398a8e000+4c2000]
Apr  6 12:36:52 EE-Test-Server kernel: [53677.956562] nginx[26724]: segfault at 30 ip 0000558398c6b2d9 sp 00007ffee2bda2b0 error 4 in nginx[558398a8e000+4c2000]
Apr  6 14:22:11 EE-Test-Server kernel: [59996.600975] nginx[27361]: segfault at 30 ip 0000558398c6b2d9 sp 00007ffee2bda240 error 4 in nginx[558398a8e000+4c2000]
Apr  6 14:24:13 EE-Test-Server kernel: [60118.378319] nginx[28313]: segfault at 30 ip 0000558398c6b2d9 sp 00007ffee2bda240 error 4 in nginx[558398a8e000+4c2000]
```

**apport.log**

```
ERROR: apport (pid 24810) Fri Apr  6 08:38:55 2018: called for pid 24682, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 24810) Fri Apr  6 08:38:55 2018: executable: /usr/sbin/nginx (command line "nginx:\ worker\ process")
ERROR: apport (pid 24810) Fri Apr  6 08:38:55 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 24810) Fri Apr  6 08:38:55 2018: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_sbin_nginx.33.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
ERROR: apport (pid 25700) Fri Apr  6 10:17:20 2018: called for pid 24811, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 25700) Fri Apr  6 10:17:20 2018: executable: /usr/sbin/nginx (command line "nginx:\ worker\ process")
ERROR: apport (pid 25700) Fri Apr  6 10:17:20 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 25700) Fri Apr  6 10:17:20 2018: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_sbin_nginx.33.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
ERROR: apport (pid 26723) Fri Apr  6 11:13:59 2018: called for pid 25701, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 26723) Fri Apr  6 11:13:59 2018: executable: /usr/sbin/nginx (command line "nginx:\ worker\ process")
ERROR: apport (pid 26723) Fri Apr  6 11:13:59 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 26723) Fri Apr  6 11:13:59 2018: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_sbin_nginx.33.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
ERROR: apport (pid 27360) Fri Apr  6 12:36:53 2018: called for pid 26724, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 27360) Fri Apr  6 12:36:53 2018: executable: /usr/sbin/nginx (command line "nginx:\ worker\ process")
ERROR: apport (pid 27360) Fri Apr  6 12:36:53 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 27360) Fri Apr  6 12:36:53 2018: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_sbin_nginx.33.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
ERROR: apport (pid 28312) Fri Apr  6 14:22:11 2018: called for pid 27361, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 28312) Fri Apr  6 14:22:11 2018: executable: /usr/sbin/nginx (command line "nginx:\ worker\ process")
ERROR: apport (pid 28312) Fri Apr  6 14:22:11 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 28312) Fri Apr  6 14:22:11 2018: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_sbin_nginx.33.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
```

Comment: Looks like defective hardware.

Comment: Migrated the whole setup to another server yet the same error.

Comment: Diagnosed it myself. It was because of Brotli. Disabled Brotli from Nginx.conf and not a single error now.